# Built-in isidentifier() function inconsistent results

Tags: python, python-3.x, built-in

I'm using built-in isidentifier() function to find Unicode chars allowed for variable names (I know about xid_start and xid_continue chars, don't need explanation on that). The following program has certain inconsistency with it's results on different systems. I'm very confused and interested about the reasoning.

```
chars = []

for char in range(0x110000):
    char = chr(char)
    if char.isidentifier() or ('a' + char).isidentifier():
        chars += [char]

print(len(chars))
```

Program results running in PyCharm gives me 134415, but running it on [repl.it](https://repl.it) gives me 128770. My python version is 3.9.7, while repl's is 3.8.12. Everything I was able to find was this [isidentifier() documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isidentifier), which gives a hint at [PEP 3131](https://peps.python.org/pep-3131/) standard which is used in Python 3. But both I and [repl.it](https://repl.it) are using same major python version, it's just minor version difference. Looking for function changelog also gives no results. Hope you will be able to help me resolve this issue!

Comment: 3.8 and 3.9 aren't really the same major version, 3.9 is the next major release of python 3 with lots more changes than your usual minor upgrade

Comment: It might be OS dependent as well. Running this code using Python 3.7.9 on MacOS 11.5 outputs 128491

Comment: @Sayse, my bad, I was not deep diving into python version scheme. But the function changelog still doesn't capture that.

Comment: @DeepSpace, Documentation doesn't mention that and I don't see it possible. Built-in function producing different results on different systems seems odd. Even if it is dependent on something like encoding, python still would be able to parse and run it. Still quite confused.

Comment: @Sayse, I will look into that this evening. But still if something internal has changed, shouldn't that result in any changelog?

Comment: @PavloffGleb *"Built-in function producing different results on different systems seems odd"* `os.path.sep` returns different output on different OS, `os.fork` does not even work on all OS

Comment: @Sayse, it seems reasonable but also very bad. How can I say what characters are allowed for certain python version (i.e. 3.4) if it's mentioned nowhere?

Comment: @DeepSpace, I was not denying that.

Comment: @Sayse, I have seen it, will try it in a few seconds)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using different versions of unicode data

Try adding to your script

```
import unicodedata

print(unicodedata.unidata_version)
```

For me, repl.it was using version 12.1.0  and my python 3.9.9 on mac 12.3 was using version 13.0.0

The pep you link to says that the characters depend on the DerivedCoreProperties.txt file thats in the unicode version used by python

[Version 12.1.0](https://www.unicode.org/Public/12.1.0/ucd/DerivedCoreProperties.txt)
[Version 13.0.0](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/ucd/DerivedCoreProperties.txt)

> The exact specification of what characters have the XID_Start or XID_Continue properties can be found in the DerivedCoreProperties file of the Unicode data in use by Python

---

This matches up to what the unicodedata module says in its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata).

When using [python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)

> The data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version 12.1.0.

When using [python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata)

> The data contained in this database is compiled from the UCD version 13.0.0.

Comment: And since you mention it in your post comments, [3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata) uses UCD 6.3.0

Comment: @PavloffGleb - Enjoy! Kudos on the well thought out question post too